# How can I get the parent site, or the site where the file was sent from, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm writing a `node.js` application with client-side javascript that uses `fetch` to get data from the node API that I wrote. I want to be able to put that application on any site (URL) without changing anything in the javascript. My current code goes something like `fetch("http://localhost:8080/data.json")`. If I wanted to deploy onto Heroku, for example, I would have to change that. Is there a way to overcome this fact?

Comment: Is the port going to be the same?

Comment: @Keith I don't think so, since it can run on the web and `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Window location might do the trick, if I am understanding correctly. Set it into a variable like this:

For browser:

If the hostname is http://localhost:8000, using this:

```
  // http://localhost:8000/data.json
    var url = window.location.hostname + "/data.json";
    fetch(url)
```

Heres another example.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Page location is " + window.location.href;
```

Result is

```
Page location is https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp
```

More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

I see you wanted NodeJS, for server

```
var os = require("os");
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000
var url = os.hostname;
var final = url + ":" + port
// localhost:port
var hostname = os.hostname();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By poking around in window.location, I found out that what you are referring to is actually `window.location.origin`

Comment: I see you were referring to NodeJs, I modified my answer. If you are running as a server environment you can use the bottom response. window.hostname works.

Comment: Although I am running a node.js server the fetch is happening from the client-side javascript

Comment: Yeah, then window.location should do the trick, just using it into a multipart variable to combine into one.  # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location